# How to create my own probability density function and get a random retrun of x in Python

Tags: python, scipy, probability-density

I'm now trying to create a function which will return a random x based on my own probability function:

y = m/pow(x,n)

m and n are values determined by user.

x belongs to [m,m+2]

I wish it can return a random number x based on the posibility.

Just as calling:

```
from numpy.random import exponential
temp = exponential(scale = 5)
```

temp will be a random number.

As my funciton is not a standerd function, so I try to use scipy.stats.rv_continuous to create a PDF function.
Here is my code:

```
from scipy import stats
m = 0.1
n = 2.3
class DK(stats.rv_continuous):
def _pdf(self, x, m,n):
   return m/pow(x,n)

mydist = DK(moment = 0,a = m,b = m + 2)
```

And as you can see, I don't know how to send the parameters: m and n into the function

I take a look at the scipy.stats.rv_continuous instuctions but can't find the solution.

Does anyone know how to send the parameters into the function?

Or anyone know other ways to reach my goal? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your only problem is getting `m` and `n` into `_pdf`, I would remove them from the function call and just write a custom `__init__` for `DK` that accepts and saves these parameters. Then you can use `self.m` and `self.n` in `_pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I find that even if I can send m and n into the function, it won't return the random number I want.  I find using a reverse transform sampling can solve my problem in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Inverse transform sampling to do the work.
[1] :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling